# Join and Group Two Tables and Get Sum of Fields - Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

There is tow tables for my products, which one is related to main warehouse and the other one is related to a little store. Both tables keep amounts of products.

```
tblWareHouse
-----------------------------------
ProductID   ProductSeries    Amount
   1           600             80
   1           601             50
   2           300             90

tblStore
-----------------------------------
ProductID   ProductSeries    Amount
   1           700             20
   1           601             40
   2           400             10
```

Every product has a unique ProductSeries number. I need to join and group these two tables and get sum of amount Products by ProductID for two warehouse and store like this:

```
Output
------------------------------------------
ProductID   StoreAmount    WareHouseAmount
    1          60               130
    2          10                90
```

My Code is this:

```
var q = from d in db.tblWareHouses
         join s in db.tblStores on d.ProductID equals s.ProductID
         group new { d, s } by d.ProductID into v
         select new
         {
             ID = Convert.ToInt32(v.Key),
             WareHouseAmount = v.Sum(x => x.d.Amount),
             StoreAmount = v.Sum(x => x.s.Amount),
         };
```

But there is a problem, it will generate extra output rows and while summing the amount it will give me more than it is. for example for ProductID 1 in warehouse it will generate 3 rows of store in joining and while summing it will sum all of the extra rows. I need to remove the duplicate ones. Hope I'm clear enough. How to fix it?

Comment: Did you try `.Distinct();` in the end?

Comment: Yes  tried but nothing. I think there is a problem with joining and grouping

Comment: your output increase distnict of your productid and your join incorrect you are need to join two tables primary key and foreign key but i see your join columns dooesnt contains primary key. d.ProductID equals s.ProductID

Comment: What ORM is this - LINQ to SQL, EF, EF Core or ? Also what is the type of the properties (can you show at least one of the classes)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the sum in each table, I was able to achieve by splitting sum into separate queries:

```
var q1 = tblWareHouses.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.ProductID)
    .Select(a => new
    {
        ProductID = a.Key,
        Amount = a.Sum(r => r.Amount)
    }).ToList();


var q2 = tblStores.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.ProductID)
    .Select(a => new
    {
        ProductID = a.Key,
        Amount = a.Sum(r => r.Amount)
    }).ToList();

var q3 = (from d in q1
    join s in q2 on d.ProductID equals s.ProductID
    group new {d, s} by d.ProductID
    into v
    select new
    {
        ID = v.Key,
        WareHouseAmount = v.Sum(x => x.d.Amount),
        StoreAmount = v.Sum(x => x.s.Amount),
    }).ToList();
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Man, Great. It works and Now I'm using it. But Also I'm looking for another way which do this query in one time joining and grouping ;)

Comment: @Nofuzy Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Join will most likely work like cartesian join between rows with the same ProductID, so it produces wrong results. I'd try to abandon join and grouping and use `Zip()` instead. It takes corresponding rows from both collections joins then together with new result. It's far from ideal solution, since it most likely will evaluate inside computer's memory. I think you can avoid this with sql, but each table needs to be projected to a collection containing row number first (ie. using `RANK` function), then join needs to be on this row number.